# Naming struct field ids in Racket when creating struct

Tags: struct, racket

I am learning Racket at the moment and would like to know if the following is possible out of the box in Racket.  When I create an instance of a class I use the following syntax:

```
(new Client% [name "John"]
             [age  30])
```

I like the fact that I need to name the field ids when creating an instance of a class.  Is there an equivalent when I am creating a struct.  I scanned the Racket documentation but could not find anything about naming field ids when creating a struct.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html), you will find that `struct` creates a constructor for you that takes the initial values of a structure instance as positional arguments. AFAIK there is no built-in support for a "keyword"-like constructor.

Having said that, you can always do something like

```
(struct client (name age))
(struct client (name age) #:transparent)
(define (new-client #:name n #:age a)
  (client n a))
(new-client #:age 20 #:name "me")
```

to get the usual function with keyword feeling.